# innerHTML for anchor tag not changing

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am trying to change the `innerHTML` for an anchor text but it is not changing....

**HTML:**

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <a id="grabLinkAll" onClick="showAll()" href="#">show all</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function showAll() {
    var theDropPosition = document.getElementById('grabLinkAll');
    if (theDropPosition.innerHTML == "show all") {
        theDropPosition.innerHTML == "hide all";
    } else {
        theDropPosition.innerHTML == "show all";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single equal for set a value

```
theDropPosition.innerHTML = "text";
```

Instead the double equal for conditions

```
if(var1==var2){ //....
```

And the triple equal for an identical check

```
var x=0;
var y=false;

if(x===y) alert('they are identical');
```

In this case the alert not appear but if was with the double equal the condition was true

Comment: +1, but I recommend clarifying further for the OP what you changed. It's not very clear from your answer at all (unless you already know the answer).

Comment: Ahhhhh I can't believe I made such a silly mistake! Thanks!